# mongodb convert array elements from int to string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb full of records with mixed types and need to sanitize data to make some sense in back end application.

To change type(NumberLong to String) of a normal field is easy, just cast it to string in Javascript like:

```js
db.foo.find({ field: { $type: 18 } }).forEach(function (x) {
  x.field = new String(x.field); // convert field to string
  db.foo.save(x);
});
```

But how do I change array elements from NumberLong to String?

For example I have field:

```json
"elements" : { "top" : {"random" : [ NumberLong(12) , NumberLong(20), NumberLong(13)] } }
```

and I need all the elements of `elements.top.random` as strings.

Do I need to do "foreach" element of the array or is there any better way?

Any Javascript guru can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Before posting I just could not find an answer, and now I did find something similar and adopted...

so here it is:

```
db.foo.find( {"elements.top.random": {$type:18}} ).forEach( function (x) {
    var arr = [];
    x.elements.top.random.forEach( function (e) { arr.push("" + e); } );
    x.elements.top.random = arr;
    db.foo.save(x);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We came across this issue today with a more recent version of MongoDB (`v4.0.0`). Since the `save()` API is deprecated, we had to use `updateOne()`, resulting in the following code:

```js
db.foo.find( {"elements.top.random": {$type:18}} ).forEach(function (x) {
    var stringValues = [];
    x.elements.top.random.forEach(function(e) {
        stringValues.push("" + e);
    });

    db.foo.updateOne(
        { _id: x._id },
        { $set: { "elements.top.random" : stringValues } }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB v4.2+, you can do an update with aggregation pipeline. Use `$reduce` and `$toString` to do the string conversion and string concat.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "elements.top.random": {
    $type: 18
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "elements.top.random": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$elements.top.random",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": {
            "$concat": [
              "$$value",
              {
                $toString: "$$this"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jfOVlTug74Y) for your reference.

---

With a slightly older version of MongoDB (v4.0+), you can still have `$toString` available. You can use the old "aggregate-then-update" approach.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "elements.top.random": {
        $type: 18
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "elements.top.random": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$elements.top.random",
          "initialValue": "",
          "in": {
            "$concat": [
              "$$value",
              {
                $toString: "$$this"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]).forEach(agg => {
  db.collection.update(
    { _id: agg._id }, 
    { $set: { "elements.top.random" : agg.elements.top.random } }
  )
})
```